# ObjectiveC - What is the significance of alloc and init?

Tags: objective-c

What is the purpose of alloc and init? (Objective -C)

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *later = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:100000];
```

Comment: In what way? They are 2 `NSDate` instances at different dates...

Comment: Can you write NSlog???

Comment: Why is the first one [[NSDate alloc] init];? Does the second one use a method instead?

Comment: `alloc`, `init` and `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` are all methods.

Comment: Think you need to read a book before asking questions like that. I recommend 'Programming in Objective-C' by Stephen Kochan.

Comment: @user2551637 "Does the second one use a method instead?" - instead of what? The first one calls two methods two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

This simply allocate the memory for an NSDate object and initialise it with the standard init method.

```
NSDate *later = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:100000];
```

Here you take the object you initialised above and use the method *dateByAddingTimeInterval* with the parameter *100000* on it, resulting in another object with the increased time interval.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.  It may be an explanation of the result of the method calls, but it is not an answer.

Comment: Yes you are right as of the moment. But the question have been changed after I answered it.. Look at the edit! He asked what the difference was.